# How to check the responses of an HTTP request?

Tags: php, android, http

I had completed a small Android project(MAP and Location based) 4 months before. Now I am planning to improve the App by upgrading the map API and some code tweaking. As a part of this, I would like to ask that how can I check the response for an HTTP request from the web-server efficiently. My current strategy is:

- App will upload the data to PHP server by using **HTTP GET** method.
- The response from server will be in the form of XML tagged format.
- I must have to check the corresponding tag for the response from server(use xmlParser example seen in Stack Overflow xml parser).

I think this is little bit annoying for me. Is there any easy method to achieve this process?

Example:
If the user tries to log-in, the credential will be checked in SERVER and successful authentication will be replied as some code: 1 else: 0.

All the HTTP requests are handled as asynctask.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String login(String login_url,List<NameValuePair> login_parameters_list) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    int response_code = -1;
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(post_url);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(post_parameters_list));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    // coockie management 
    httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getName();
    response_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if(response_code == 999 || response_code == HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    {
        Log.e("HttpResponse", "Internal Server");

    }
    else if(response_code == -1 )
    {
        Log.e("HttpResponse", "Socket connection timeout");

    }
    if (response_code == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
    {
        // credential check failed
        Log.e("HTTP status", "unauthorised");

    }
    else if (response_code == HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN)
    {
        // forbidden
        Log.e("HTTP status", "Forbidden");

    }
    return response_code == HttpStatus.SC_OK ? EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()) : null;
}
```